# Python 3.5 No Module named xlrd or pybrain

Tags: python, python-3.5

I am working on a project to build a Neural Net in python from an xlrd file, and I am encountering some issues. I have installed xlrd using pip install xlrd, and pybrain by cloning the git repository and running `python setup.py install` both of which were successful in installing. When I try to run `import xlrd` or `import pybrain` from IDLE, it gives the error:

```
>>> import xlrd
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import xlrd
ImportError: No module named 'xlrd'
```

and the same thing for pybrain. I only have python 3.5 installed. I am at the end of my rope with this, If anyone can give some insight in to why this may be happening I would be very appreciative.

Comment: Did you completely exit and restart IDLE after installing the new packages? Also, what is the output of `pip -V`?

Comment: Yes, I have restarted IDLE several times.  pip -V gives: pip 8.1.2 from c:users\[Me]\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (python 3.5). It may be worth noting that I installed anaconda after I had python installed, and that the IDLE i am trying to run this from is what I originally installed. I don't think that should matter though.

Comment: Absolutely it does. You apparently have two separate installations of Python, contrary to what you state in your question - the original Python 3.5 (presumably from python.org) and the Anaconda distribution, which is entirely separate from the first. If `pip` is installing to Anaconda, then use Anaconda's IDLE to mess around, and Anaconda's `python3.exe` (or maybe `python.exe`, I don't use it) for running files on the command line.

Answer (score 0):

Had this same problem with Python 3.6. Issue fixed by doing a PIP install of the XLRD.

```
pip install xlrd
```